# How does infinite scroll work in case of caching redis

Tags: reactjs, caching, redis

In case of no cache, infinite scroll works, but when you add cache code, the data repeats when pagination is finished. how can i solve. I am doing a clone project. I'm new to redis, I'd be very grateful if you could reply.  I can't think of anything about it (:
Backend my code

```
const searchpost = async (req, res) => {
      let perpage = 3;
      const value = req.query.q;
      const pageNumber = req.query.page;
    
      try {
        const redisPosts = await client.keys("Blog*");
        if (redisPosts.length > 0) {
          async.map(
            redisPosts,
            async function (redisPost) {
              const cacheBlog = await client.get(redisPost);
              let parseData = JSON.parse(cacheBlog);
              let job = { ...parseData };
    
              return job;
            },
            function (err, results) {
              if (err) throw err;
    
              res.status(200).json({ searcharticles: results });
            }
          );
        } else {
          const searcharticles = await Blog.find({
            $or: [
              { title: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
              { tag: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
              { Subtitle: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
            ],
          })
            .skip((pageNumber - 1) * perpage)
            .limit(perpage)
            .populate("authorId");
    
          async.map(
            searcharticles,
            async function (searcharticle) {
              let cacheKey = `Blog:` + uuidv4();
    
              await client.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(searcharticle));
              return searcharticles;
            },
            function (err, searcharticles) {
              if (err) throw err;
    
              res.status(200).json({ searcharticles });
            }
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "hata durumu oluştu" });
      }
    };
```

infinity scroll react code

```
export const SearchPost = (query, pageNumber) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false);
  const [userInfo, setuserInfo] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setBlogs([]);
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    let cancel;
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `/api/search`,
      params: { q: query, page: pageNumber },
      withCredentials: true,
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setBlogs((prevBlog) => {
          return [
            ...new Set([...prevBlog, ...res.data.searcharticles.map((b) => b)]),
          ];
        });
        setHasMore(res.data.searcharticles.length);
        setLoading(false);
        setuserInfo(res.data.userInfo);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) return;
        setError(true);
      });

    return () => cancel();
  }, [query, pageNumber]);

  return { loading, error, blogs, hasMore, userInfo };
};


const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const { ısAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { blogs, hasMore, loading } = SearchPost(query, pageNumber);

  const observer = useRef();
  const lastBlogElementRef = useCallback(
    (node) => {
      if (loading) return;
      if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
          //burda verıyı gecıp gecmedıgını kontrol etmelıyız
          setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);
        }
      });
      if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
    },
    [loading, hasMore]
  );

  function handleSearch(e) {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
    setPageNumber(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing for those who encounter this problem, you don't need to do a for loop. You can do this by typing the number of pages into the key. The edited code is below.

```
const searchpost = async (req, res) => {
  let perpage = 3;
  const value = req.query.q;
  const pageNumber = req.query.page;
  const query = `Blog:` + "/" + pageNumber;
  try {
    let redisPosts = await client.get(query);

    if (redisPosts) {
      redisPosts = JSON.parse(redisPosts);
      res.status(200).json({ searcharticles: redisPosts });
    } else {
      const searcharticles = await Blog.find({
        $or: [
          { title: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
          { tag: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
          { Subtitle: { $regex: value, $options: "i" } },
        ],
      })
        .skip((pageNumber - 1) * perpage)
        .limit(perpage)
        .populate("authorId");

      let cacheKey = query;

      await client.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(searcharticles));
      res.status(200).json({ searcharticles });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "hata durumu oluştu" });
  }
};
```